# Passing $(this) to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with implementing this ColorPicker plugin:

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

I have a form with multiple fields, and I'd like the color picker to pop-up when I select any field, and change the value based on the selection made.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function changeColor(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).ColorPicker({
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $(this).attr('value', '#' + hex)
            }
        });
    }
    $('form.niceform input').live('mouseup', changeColor);
})
```

for some reason though, the $(this).attr... section is not recognizing that $(this) is the currently selected field.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At that point, $(this) is the colorpicker, not the element that you applied the colorpicker to.

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function changeColor(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.ColorPicker({
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                elem.attr('value', '#' + hex)
            }
        });
    }
    $('form.niceform input').live('mouseup', changeColor);
})
```

**EDIT:** As Pointy pointed out, there are a couple things you could do to make this a bit better:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function changeColor(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.ColorPicker({
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                elem.val('#' + hex)
            }
        });
    }
    $('form.niceform input').on('mouseup', changeColor);
})
```

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that that's a goofy way to set the value attribute (use `.val()` instead), and that `.live()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function changeColor(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = $(this);

        self.ColorPicker({
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                self.val('#' + hex);
            }
        });
    }
    $('form.niceform input').live('mouseup', changeColor);
});
```

You should place the `$(this)` outside the `ColorPicker` function into a variable.

Comment: One quick question... where is the scope gate? I thought that the ColorPicker object defines a scope, so I didn't know I can pass a variables all the way down to the function call within the onChange method.

Comment: The scope is the function, inside `onChange`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function changeColor(e) {
        var self = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        $(self).ColorPicker({
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $(self).attr('value', '#' + hex)
            }
        });
    }
    $('form.niceform input').live('mouseup', changeColor);
})
```